# Safari not respecting padding

Tags: css, svg, safari

I'm currently working on a page which has a series of svgs on it, created dynamically using (the frankly amazing) d3.js.

Everything is fine, except I'm getting a weird issue in Safari (Version 9.1.1 (10601.6.17) on Mac OS X (Yosemite, repeatable on El Capitan with latest Safari 9.1)) whereby things are misaligned. I have two svgs right next to each other which for all intents and purposes have all of the same margin, padding etc. definitions, yet one of them sits properly (with 14px of padding-top), whereas the other (in theory also with 14px padding-top) seems to completely ignore this padding and sit 14px higher. As can be seen in the below images, I've used Safari's built in developer tools, and the padding does seem to be correctly defined, it's just decided not to care.

[image: left svg (correct)]

compared to:
[image: right svg (incorrect)]

It's worth noting that this issue repeats for as many of these svg-pairs as I have, so it's not just happening in a single instance (in  both images you can see the same phenomenon recurring).

Another weird / interesting element of this is that when I zoom out (using ⌘ + ⇧ + -), the issue seems to resolve itself. This only occurs at the default zoom level.

Any help / pointers are greatly appreciated. I wouldn't describe myself as a front-end developer in any meaningful fashion, I'm really doing this due to necessity, so it's entirely possible I'm doing something very very silly.

This all works perfectly on Chrome.

Comment: I had once the issue, that i used decimals in my css and safari rounds them up or down. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response @olivier. I've posted the solution I came across below, and as mentioned your advice led me towards the right direction, so thank you. I have also made sure that apart from the padding, my widths and heights etc are all integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following up on [olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970507/olivier)'s suggestion, I was fixing some non-integer widths / heights which unfortunately didn't work, but while doing that I was looking at the padding and decided to try tweaking it. Long story short, apparently Safari was throwing a fit because of the svgs attempting to perfectly touch. Having padding-right as 0 on the left-hand svg and padding-left as 0 on the right svg seemed to be the issue. The fix was to set both paddings to 0.02px (seems to be the lowest I could go without it giving trouble). This leaves a very VERY subtle seam between the two svgs, but obviously this is a vast improvement on misaligning them.